# Фильтрация данных GridView

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть таблица вывода данных GridView,  нужно сделать фильтр данных по условию: если в одной Модели1 значение записи равно значению записи в Модели2, то выводить записи в таблице. Модели никак не связаны между собой.

Т.е., получается, что нужно сравнить данные из двух несвязанных таблиц.

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$models = Model1::find()
    //...
    ->all();

$model2 = Model2::find()
    ->select(['column'])
    //...
    ->asArray()
    ->column();

$model2 = array_flip($model2);

$models = array_filter($models, function($item) use ($model2) {
    return array_key_exists($item['column'], $model2);
});
```

В итоге `$models` будет содержать только те элементы которые содержаться в `$model2`.

Но как вы собираетесь строить `paging`? Я бы использовал join в sql запросе чтобы отсечь все ненужные элементы ещё на уровне db.